# Are there any smart print methods in Python?

Tags: python, list

I want a smart print for list. For example:

```
a=[2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I want the print result like: `2*3, 1*7`

Not like: `2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1`

Comment: What have you already tried? What does not work?

Comment: `itertools.groupby` or `collections.Counter` should help

Comment: I only know pprint: http://pymotw.com/2/pprint/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> a = [2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]    
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> ["{}*{}".format(k, sum(1 for x in g)) for k, g in groupby(a)]
['2*3', '1*7']
```

Or in the interests of code reuse:

```
>>> def rle(seq):
...     return ((k, sum(1 for x in g)) for k, g in groupby(seq))
... 
>>> ["{}*{}".format(*x) for x in rle(a)]
['2*3', '1*7']
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I guess we need a way to determine which ones are countable first. But the `sum(...)` makes me cringe every time...

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with "Run this on an infinite iterable at your own risk!".

Comment: @alecxe, no it doesn't. The question is underspecified concerning disjoint runs, so any interpretation can work for now

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.Counter` if the order doesn't matter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
>>> ",".join(("%s*%s" % (item, count) for item, count in Counter(a).iteritems()))
'1*7,2*3'
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yup. Works in case the OP doesn't need to save the order.

Comment: Also doesn't handle disjoint runs well.

Answer (score 1):

You want simple RLE (run-length encoding), you can do it like this

```
from itertools import groupby
return [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(a)]
```

you will get a list of tuples, the first item of each tuple being the number in the original array, and the second item being the group length.